# C# Query: Command Window does not persist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code for a button click event. This event should open the command window and execute the application:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == " " || textBox2.Text == " ")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Header File or Executable Missing");
            }
            else
            {
                Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
                string filename = textBox1.Text;
                int found = filename.LastIndexOf("\\");
                int end = filename.Length;
                string temp = filename.Substring(found);
                startInfo.Arguments = temp + textBox2.Text;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
        }
```

The problem that I'm facing out here is that when I click the button, the command window does not persist and I don't know whether the command window displays an error message or not because it opens & closes in a flash. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here and give me a few hints how to go about solving the issue?

Comment: what type of application are you starting with your process command?

Comment: Hi @MarkHall, It is a .exe application generated by Visual C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start a new console application from your Windows Forms application you need to either pass in the path to such an application or to cmd.exe + the run command for that application. Make sure the code in your console application halts by asking for a Console.ReadKey(true) or similar.

Comment: Thank you. How different will it be a for a Windows Form application? THe above is a windows form application.

Comment: Are you saying you're asking your Windows Forms application to start another Windows Forms application? If that's the case what's the "command window" you're referring to?

Comment: Looking more closely at your coding details. Have you checked that your startInfo contains the correct path by inspecting it in the debugger? Also, you should consider using the Path class' static methods for joining paths etc. Much less error-prone

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I mean the command prompt. It is pointing to the path. I'll try doing as you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure but does the UseShellExecute start info option allow an app to continue when the main app terminates? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx - might be nothing but...